# Строить таблицу в js или php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Прошу дать совет. Как лучше выводить таблицы с данными из базы MySQL.

AJAX запрос к серверу. Получаем данные таблицы с базы.
Передаем с сервера на клиент.
Выводим в браузер.

Вопрос:

1. Сделать разметку в PHP и передать готовую таблицу для вывода в JS.

или

2. Передать JSON с данными на клиент и уже там сделать разметку таблицы в JS.

Есть ли разница или нет?
Ведь в первом случае размер данных которые передаются будет больше, а во втором нагрузка на браузер больше. Или я не прав?

Comment: Я начинал с первого варианта. Но сейчас только вторым способом. Вся генерация HTML кода на фронте. Так или иначе c JSON придется работать, будь Вы бэкэнд или фронтенд разработчиком.

Comment: Тут зависит от контекста приложения. Для отображения достаточно первого варианта. Если будет активная работа с данными (ну сортировка там, или фильтрация) - возможно второй.

Comment: @NoSkill ну это понятно. Ну например если для отображения. Если размер данных не большой то думаю без разницы. А если большой, то как лучше?

Comment: Разница конечно есть, и очень существенная. Но ответ зависит от очень многих факторов. Используете ли вы фреймворки на фронте по типу react\angular\vue. Как вы будете строить этот html на фронте? Плюс, что за структура html в конце концов нужна?

Comment: Ну а насколко большой? Если там десятки и сотни тысяч строк, то на медленных машинах JS будет тормозить и блокировать браузер. Тогда нужно загружать/обрабатывать порционно. В каждом конкретном случае есть свои плюсы и минусы. Если данных много, вопрос еще и в том загружать работой сервер или клиент.